# Visa entry to North Macedonia

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, multiple-entry, macedonia

Do I have to enter a Schengen country first that issued the visa before entering Macedonia? I’ve contacted the Embassy and they said I don’t have to as long as it’s valid multiple entry type c and valid at least 5 days after my planned stay. I checked IATA and there’s no mention about using the Schengen visa once to enter Macedonia.

But anyone experienced travelling first to Macedonia with a Schengen visa and not having problems?

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of such a requirement. How come?

[Every visit is limited to 15 days, but up to 90 days are allowed per 180 day period.](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=134&Itemid=662&lang=en)

Comment: So u saying I shouldn’t have any problems in the immigration in Macedonia?